# MVC Code First and Look up tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, lookup-tables

What is the good way to handle look up tables in MVC designed with Code First EF. Here is the scenario: I have two tables, first one is Location and Second one is Language. Each table has Id and Name properties in them. Now I need to figure out implementation of look up location by language. Each location has ability to have multiple languages. I am thinking what will be the  best approach to get this implemented? Do I need look up table which will have separate row for each location/language combination?

Answer (score 0):

Approach that I took is to implement classic look up table which linked to both parents table. I've used EF power tools to revert engineer to code first to get all relationships correctly done.